# Print a grade Distribution chart of all students using stars to determine each time a grade appears

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

As the title states. I now completed most of my code for the program, and this is the last piece. To be honest, at this point I am just not understanding how to carry this out. I know I should use implement this similar to how the grade letters are implemented, but how do I implement it in such a way that for each grade within a grade range the distribution chart will add an asterisk in relevant grade range.

Essentially the distribution chart should look like this:

Overall Grade Distribution:

0-9:

10-19:

20-29:

30-39:

40-49:

50-59:

60-69: ***

70-79: ******

80-89: ***********

90-99: *******

100: ***

Thought it may be better to have all the code available through a link so here you go:

[This is my code on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n1Qy3H)

I was trying to figure this out. I was told to loop from 0 to 100 by 10's and then the nested loop loops from 0 to the amount of stars. N is equal to the amount of students and 5 is relevant to the amount of grades per student:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + (i + 10));
    for (int j = 0; j < (n*5); j++)
    {
        // add stars here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code at .net fiddle first of all you need to implement some way to get the grades back from student, in my example i used GetGrades Method. Second of all i'm sure that there are better or clearer way than this (linq), but hey at least it works :)

```
        // Array where each value represents number of grades within range
        // distribution[0]: 0 - 9
        // distribution[1]: 10 - 19
        // distribution[2]: 20 - 29
        // distribution[3]: 30 - 39
        // distribution[4]: 40 - 49
        // distribution[5]: 50 - 59
        // distribution[6]: 60 - 69
        // distribution[7]: 70 - 79
        // distribution[8]: 80 - 89
        // distribution[9]: 90 - 99
        // distribution[10]: 100
        var distribution = new int[11]; 
        // Fill the array with distribtions for all students 
        // *Don't forget to implement GetGradse method for student 
        foreach (var s in students)
        foreach (var g in s.GetGrades())
        {
            // skip the grade thats less than 0 or greater than 100 (invalid grade)
            // in every other case increment distribution at g / 10 index
            if (g < 0 || g > 100) continue;
            else distribution[(int)g / 10]++;
        }
        // Now we can print out the grades distribution
        for (var i = 0; i < distribution.Length - 1; i++)
            Console.WriteLine($"{i * 10}-{i * 10 + 9}: {new String('*', distribution[i])}");
        Console.WriteLine($"100: {new String('*', distribution[10])}");
```

**EDIT (Another way of doing this, printing part stays the same):** You could also declare the distribution array up alongside students array and fill it up at the same place where you assign grades to students, if you do it this way you won't need to loop trought all the students and grades again:

```
            ...
            Student[] students = new Student[n];
            var distribution = new int[11];
            ...
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter grade {j + 1} for student {i + 1}: ");
                double grade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                students[i].addGrade(grade);
                // assuming grade value won't be greater than 100 or less than 0
                distributions[(int)grade / 10]++;
            }
            ...
            ...
```